# openlayers3 - customize ol.interaction.Modify behavior to redraw polygons

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I was wondering if it's possible to customize the behavior of the Modify interaction so it behaves like it did in openlayers 2 (with OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature) for Polygons.

I'm looking to mimic this behavior:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/modify-feature.html

[image] [image]

[on the left: openlayers3 - on the right: openlayers 2]

Openlayers3 doesn't seem to draw the corner points of the polygons + also, I would like to have the "vertices creating" feature (the points in the middle of the lines of the polygon) from the demo.

I do like that with the ol3 modify feature you can edit the shape everywhere you want but for end users, the interaction might not be that obvious if there are no visual indications to reshape the polygon.

So to summarize: I'm looking for a way to add the visual indications to modify a shape with the ol.interaction.Modify control to bring back the ol2 behavior. I would like to know IF this is possible by customizing this control or IF it's possible to mimic this behavior in any other way OR if I'm out of luck.

using openlayers v3.19

Comment: To Edit the shape write custom interaction using ol.interaction.Pointer instead of using ol.interaction.Modify. I did that for my project to reshape the polygon by moving the vertices of it.